# Disabled close button enables when moving the dialog

Tags: button, mfc, dialog, isenabled

So i want to disable [X] close button of MFC dialog while some process is running. I do it like this:

```
void CSomeDlg::EnableCloseButton(BOOL bEnable)
{
    UINT menuf = bEnable ? (MF_BYCOMMAND) : (MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED | MF_DISABLED);

    CMenu* pSM = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if(pSM)
        pSM->EnableMenuItem(SC_CLOSE, menuf);
}

void CSomeDlg::OnBtnClick_Cancel()
{
    if (!isSomeProcess)     
        CDialogEx::OnCancel();

}

void CSomeDlg::main()
{
    StartSomeProcess();
    isSomeProcess = true;
    EnableCloseButton(FALSE);

    //...

    EndSomeProcess();
    isSomeProcess = false;
    EnableCloseButton(TRUE);
}
```

This works. Close button disables while some process is running. But if i move the dialog by dragging it with mouse the close button for some reason enables. And when i click on it application throws the crash error but it still working. And if i would't push the "Close application" button in the error dialog the application will finish the work correctly and error dialog will dissapear.

Why does close button enables? How to prevent it?

Comment: I tried this in a very basic dialog based sample application and it works. Once the close button is disabled it doesn't get enabled when I move the dialog around. Did you check no one calls EnableCloseButton(TRUE) when you  move the dialog ? But a breakpoint in this function and check.

Comment: I checked one more time with breakpoint and i didn't find any EnableCloseButton() calls except 2 calls in the sample code above. It's strange

Comment: Do you have an OnMove handler for your dialog ? If yes remove it and look if it works. Also create a new project from scratch and try disabling the close button there and see if it works or not. If it works there, it must be some problem in your software.

Comment: There is no OnMove handler. I tried new project and it worked. So the problem is probably somewhere else. Thanks for your help!